# Javascript Promise throwing Uncaught (in promise) -1 in console

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise

I wrote a test case for native Promise using Jasmine 2.3.4.
All my tests passes, but if i look inside browser console i see "Uncaught (in promise) -1". Below link contains my test code, and if you view the console you will see the error

https://output.jsbin.com/nogoduhone

```
describe("Promise working", function() {

          var promiseResolve = null,
              promiseReject = null;

          beforeEach(function(done) {

              promiseResolve = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                                  resolve(1);
                              });

             promiseReject = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                                 reject(-1); //causing error in console????Uncaught (in promise) -1
                               });
              done();
          });

          it("Promise is defined", function(done) {
              //console.log('Promise',promiseResolve,promiseReject);
              expect(promiseResolve).toBeDefined();
              expect(promiseReject).toBeDefined();
              done();
          });

          it("Promise is resolving properly", function(done) {
              promiseResolve.then(function(val){//success
                  expect(val).toEqual(1);
                  done();
              }).catch(function(val){
                    fail('Promise resolving should not run');
                    done();
              });
          });

         it("Promise is rejecting properly", function(done) {
             promiseReject.then(function(val){
               fail('Promise rejecting should not run');
             }).catch(function(val){
                   expect(val).toEqual(-1);
                   done();
             });
         });
      });
```

How do i fix this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, in your first two tests a `promiseReject` is created and rejected, but noone catches the error. That's what is called an "unhandled rejection". It's not an error, but a warning - ignore it, or catch it.

Comment: @Surya You can test Bergi's suggestion by making the first `it` into an `xit` so it's excluded, and see if you still get the warning

Comment: @Bergi Sorry i dont understand? Do you mean to enclose my reject promise in try catch?

Comment: No, just put a `.catch(…)` on it like in your third test case.

Comment: @JuanMendes i still get the error when adding xit. And my third test case also shows Uncaught (in promise). In total i see two errors in console